# Regular Expressions-VAlidation String-REAL noob question :)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

Im a bit embarrased asking this, so i'll just come straight out with it. I really really don't understand the technical help so maybe someone can dumb it down.

Im trying to create a validation string to allow EITHER one OR two digits (no more, no less).

These are my efforts, they all only work for the first part (first set of brackets)

Im using Visual Studio validation controls btw.

([0-9])|([0-9][0-9])
(\d{1})|(\d{2})

I would really appreciate a good laymans explanation. Many Thanks :)

Thanks to Cfreak for the solution. I would really appreciate a link or a good simple explanation of building strings. Most of what Ive read seems to expect a certain level of knowlege :)

Comment: Could this be integrated into a Regular expression Wiki as an example?  Regular expressions are one of the most powerful things I've found in the last few years.  The web is lacking a good lay person regular expression HOW-TO site; IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I'm not very familiar with .NET but any of these of these should work:

```
\d{1,2}
```

or

```
\d\d?
```

I'd go with this as it's the most compact :)

or

```
[0-9]{1,2}
```

or

```
[0-9][0-9]?
```

put ( ) around any of them to capture the matched digits.

Comment: @andrew - realized this and fixed :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Simple, Concise and effective (and saved me a whole load of time!!) +1 :)